# Construct the path that links to the customized method in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes

I have a non-standard method *listByName* in the OrdersController, as shown below.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
     def index
         @orders=Order.all
     end 

     def listByName(name)
        @orders=Order.find_by(:name=>name)
        render index        
     end
end
```

I want to create some links that can be routed to the OrdersController#listByName method.

```
<%= link_to 'listByName', listByName_path %>
```

My problem is how to construct the path in the *html.erb* page， and how to write the router.rb? 
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're going against conventions here? Use the `index` method with a sort parameter, and don't name Ruby methods and variables with camel case (use snake case).

Answer (score 0):

See [the routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Your question is answered in 1.1 and 1.2.

> 1.1 Connecting URLs to Code When your Rails application receives an incoming request for:
>
> ```
> GET /patients/17
> ```
>
> it asks the router to match it to a controller
>   action. If the first matching route is:
>
> ```
> get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'
> ```
>
> the request is dispatched to
>   the patients controller's show action with `{ id: '17' }` in params.
>
> 1.2 Generating Paths and URLs from Code You can also generate paths and URLs. If the route above is modified to be:
>
> ```
> get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'
> ```
>
> and your application contains this code in the controller:
>
> ```
> @patient = Patient.find(17)
> ```
>
> and this in the corresponding view:
>
> ```
> <%= link_to 'Patient Record', patient_path(@patient) %> then the
> ```
>
> router will generate the path `/patients/17`. This reduces the
>   brittleness of your view and makes your code easier to understand.
>   Note that the id does not need to be specified in the route helper.

Comment: The problem is I do not know what the path should be, e.g., the method `patient_path` in the ``<%link_to ...%>`` here.

Comment: See: 1.2 above, and 3.6 in the linked documentation.